# Не могу понять многие атрибуты и их расшифровку

Tags: python, arp, scapy

Не давно я стал читать книгу 'Black hat python' только потому что меня заинтересовал модуль scapy, и я не смог найти много информации в официальной документации.Но и в этой книге тоже я не нашел подробного описания.
Так вот кто знает пожалуйста откликнитесь. Кто знает напишите расшифровку этих атрибутов и для чего они нужны: sr,srp,dst,pdst,hwdst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pdst** - Target protocol address (TPA).

**hwdst** - Target hardware address (THA).

Немного информации про TPA и THA можно тут прочитать: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol

**dst mac** – IP v4 multicast MAC.

**dst ip** – IP v4 multicast address.

**sr()** отправляет запрос, а затем ждет ответ на этот запрос в сети.

**srp()** отправляет и получает пакеты:

```
Send and receive packets at layer 2
nofilter: put 1 to avoid use of BPF filters
retry:    if positive, how many times to resend unanswered packets
          if negative, how many times to retry when no more packets are answered
timeout:  how much time to wait after the last packet has been sent
verbose:  set verbosity level
multi:    whether to accept multiple answers for the same stimulus
filter:   provide a BPF filter
iface:    work only on the given interface
```

Вызывать документацию функций можно из консоли(чаще всего крупные модули сопровождаются с доктестами, следовательно все документируется).

Пример вызова: `scapy.all.srp.__doc__`.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ. У меня появился ещё 1 вопрос на эту тему, если сможешь,  ответь пожалуйста . Что такое src,psrc,hwsrc и что такое op. Пример: send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip,
 hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=gateway_mac),count=5) ,  r[Ether].src .